# Create a private network between VMWare Linux(guest) and an embedded board

Tags: linux, lan, vmware, static-ip, private-network

I am running Ubuntu on a VMWare on Windows host. I have a target embedded board(eg. Raspberry Pi) which is running Linux. I have connected the ethernet port of board and my Windows host using an ethernet cable to create a private LAN network.

I want to create a private network between the VMWare Ubuntu and my target embedded board with static IPs assigned to both of them in the same network. How do I proceed with this?

I could only find information on creating a network between host and guest, but I have an additional board. So I am confused.

Comment: Sorry.. I totally don't have an answer for you but Raspberry Pi is NOT AN EMBEDDED BOARD (not even close).  It might help you solve your problem quicker by acknowledging this.  RasPi's are Linux/ARM, not embedded and follow the same rules as any Linux box.  Searching for "private network crossover linux windows" might yield better results.  First make it where the windows box can see it before attempting to bridge the connection to your VM.

Comment: So I was able to establish the communication between my target board and Windows PC. They both have a static IP assigned to them and can ping each other. I configured the bridge connection between my VMWare and Windows host, assigned a static IP to VMWare guest. However I am unable to even ping from Windows Host to VMWare guest and vice versa.